# delete &nbsp; , &rlm; and others same characters in php

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel I want to show a demo of blog posts content and I need to remove all html elements from the content and show the first 100 characters of the posts to the users, so I am using this code:

```
{{ Str::limit(strip_tags($post->content), 100, ' ...') }}
```

but in output i see many of html element like `&nbsp;` , `&rlm;` and ...
how can i remove these elements from output?

Comment: Generally speaking [html_entity_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) will convert entities to their respective chars.

Answer (score 0):

in controller do these steps

```
$postcontent = strip_tags($post->content)
$postcontent = str_replace("&nbsp"," ",$postcontent);
$postcontent = str_replace("&rlm","",$postcontent );
```

then in blade.file

```
{{ Str::limit($postcontent), 100, ' ...') }}
```